# Wordpress custom shortcode function with variable string (Newbie)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a simple Wordpress shortcode based function that will take a defined number and convert it to the end user's local currency. Where I am stuck is how to search the post for the shortcode because the defined number is subject to change. If someone could please let me know how best to extract the number as a variable, I can then run it through the exchange rate function (which works fine, I have tested it with custom field stored data).

```
{customShortcode - priceAdditions [400]}
```

I have tried to `explode()` it around the `[]` and that seems to show promise but I can't work out how to extract it, also with the prospect of more than one instance of this being used with different numbers. I think `regex` or `preg_match` may be the way to go but I don't quite understand that just yet.

If you need more info, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Dan

Edit - The function for the shortcode that works -

```
$thePostContent =   get_the_content($post->ID); 
$thePostContent =   str_replace('{customShortcode - price}',thePrice(),$thePostContent);
```

The function -

```
function thePrice(){
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
 $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
$Exploded_URL = explode("/",$pageURL);
if      ($Exploded_URL[4] == ''){$thePostIsIn   =   217;}
elseif  ($Exploded_URL[4] == 'productA'){$thePostIsIn   =   347;}
elseif  ($Exploded_URL[4] == 'productB'){$thePostIsIn   =   345;}
else    {$thePostIsIn   =   217;}
if      (empty($_COOKIE['userLocate']) || $_COOKIE['userLocate'] == 'US' || ($_COOKIE['userLocate'] != 'EU' && $_COOKIE['userLocate'] != 'AU' && $_COOKIE['userLocate'] != 'GB')){
    $currencyCode   =   'USD';
    $currencyPrefix =   '$';
}
elseif  ($_COOKIE['userLocate'] == 'EU'){
    $currencyCode   =   'EUR';
    $currencyPrefix =   '&euro;';
}
elseif  ($_COOKIE['userLocate'] == 'AU'){
    $currencyCode   =   'AUD';
    $currencyPrefix =   'A$';
}
elseif  ($_COOKIE['userLocate'] == 'GB'){
    $currencyCode   =   'GBP';
    $currencyPrefix =   '&pound;';
}
else {
    $currencyCode   =   'USD';
    $currencyPrefix =   '$';
}

$args=array(
'post_type' =>'page',
'post__in' => array($thePostIsIn)
);
$recent_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){    

    $mypages        =   get_post( $recent->ID );
    $theBaseRate    =   get_post_meta($recent->ID, "Payment Cost",1);

    if(get_post_meta($recent->ID, "Payment Period",1)){
        $payPeriod  =   get_post_meta($recent->ID, "Payment Period",1);
    }
    else{
        $payPeriod  =   "per month";
    }

    $rssFeedUrl     =   "http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/GBP/rss.xml";
    $rss            =   simplexml_load_file($rssFeedUrl);
    foreach($rss->channel->item as $feedItem){
        $currency   =   explode('/',$feedItem->title);
        if(strpos($currency[0], $currencyCode )!== false){
            $content    =   $feedItem->description;
            $content    =   explode('= ',$content);
            $content    =   substr($content[1],0,7);
            $theCost    =   $theBaseRate * $content;
            $theCost    =   number_format($theCost, 2, '.', '');
        }
    }
}
echo '<p class="rentCost"><span class="rentalCost">'.$currencyPrefix.$theCost.' '.$payPeriod.'</span></p><div class="clear"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your shortcode code?

Comment: {customShortcode - priceAdditions [400]}

Comment: The one that works, with the number in the custom field is {customShortcode - price[$customFieldMetaPrice]}, but as this one is in the actual post, I can't seem to work out how to specifically take a price given to convert it to the end-user's local currency

Comment: Shortcodes usually look like `[myshortcode param1="something" param2="something else"]` in the editor and you should have a function defined for the shortcode.  Can you show me the function defined for the shrotcode?

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I decided to use curleys so that they are obviously different from a WP plugin's shortcode. Shortcode in retrospect is probably the wrong term. I've updated the question.

Comment: that is the beauty of using a system such as wordpress is that you can build onto their system not completely write something new.  They have done all the complex stuff and you can leverage it by using their built-in functions.  I have provided an example on how to convert your current code to accommodate the built in shortcode api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the built-in [shortcode api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) from wordpress.

In your `functions.php`

```
function thePrice( $atts ) {


   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'price' => 0 //default price
    ), $atts ) );

    //$price is now available and will hold the user entered price 
    //in the example below this would be 400

    /*
     Your conversion code here
     */

}

add_shortcode( 'convert_price', 'thePrice' );
```

How to use the shortcode in the editor

`[convert_price price="400"]`

Now you can simply use `the_content()` in your template loop and the shortcodes will be properly rendered.

Comment: Thanks @Jrod. This makes MUCH more sense, tying myself up in knots. Is there a way of being able to use this more than once in a post? Functions cannot be re-declared.

Answer (score 2):

I know where you're trying to go with the custom shortcode, but why don't you stick with Wordpress's build-in machinery for shortcodes and let it do the heavy lifting? [The official docs say](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

> "The API handles all the tricky parsing, eliminating the need for
>   writing a custom regular expression for each shortcode. Helper
>   functions are included for setting and fetching default attributes."

Your code could become:

`[priceAdditions price="400"]`

and with a short little addition to `functions.php`, you could get your data.

Comment: Thanks @jnunn. Sorry, I tied myself up in a knot for no apparent reason here!

Comment: I've done similar :) I'm finding most of the time reinventing the wheel is a waste of my time